# is Marshal.GenerateGuidForType different to GetType().GUID?

Tags: c#, .net, marshalling

just wondering if these are two methods to achieve the same thing?

note: `GetType().GUID` picks up the `GuidAttribute` okay. So is the `Marshal.GenerateGuidForType` method doing anything extra?

```
[Guid("DC05F01B-32FC-4CCE-AC0D-854E8B6471FC")]
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815096/whats-the-difference-between-marshal-generateguidfortypetype-and-type-guid (which has a more comprehensive answer too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [the documentation for `Marshal.GenerateGuidForType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.generateguidfortype.aspx):

> GenerateGuidForType provides the same functionality as the Type.GUID property.

Comment: missed that. Thanks. btw: Same comment is there even on the 1.1 version of the framework.